# Unity Wont Skip Splash Screen On Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made game using unity and its working in the editor.

But when I build it and play it on phone, it stucks on the splash screen.

How can I fix this? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have 2 scenes, one for main menu and other one for the game scene.

But you forgot to add the main menu scene to build, so your unready game scene gives error about null references so its not being able to skip the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the issue intermittently. It seems that Windows sometimes loses the focus to the application.

There is a very simple way to stop Windows losing focus which may work: As soon as the black screen appears, drag the mouse cursor down to the bottom of the screen until it disappears! The application should then continue to open normally without Windows interruption. This is only a workaround but that is all I can offer.